# Python readline() and readlines() not working

Tags: python, file, readline, readlines

I'm trying to read the contents of a 5GB file and then sort them and find duplicates. The file is basically just a list of numbers (each on a new line). There are no empty lines or any symbols other than digits. The numbers are all pretty big (at least 6 digits). I am currently using

```
for line in f:
    do something to line
```

to avoid memory problems. I am fine with using that. However, I am interested to know why readline() and readlines() didn't work for me. When I try

```
print f.readline(10)
```

the program always returns the same line no matter which number I use as a parameter. To be precise, if I do readline(0) it returns an empty line, even though the first line in the file is a big number. If I try readline(1) it returns 2, even though the number 2 is not in the file. When the parameter is >= 6, it always returns the same number: 291965.

Additionally, the readlines() method always returns the same lines no matter what the parameter is. Even if I try to print f.readlines(2), it's still giving me a list of over 1000 numbers.

I am not sure if I explained it very well. Sorry, English is not my first language. Anyway, I can make it work without the readline methods but I really want to know why they don't work as expected.

This is what the first 10 lines of the file look like:

```
548098
968516
853181
485102
69638
689242
319040
610615
936181
486052
```

Comment: `readline(10)` does not mean "read line number 10", but "read a line, but read a maximum of 10 bytes"

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce `f.readline(1)` returning `2`, or `f.readlines(10)` returning "thousands of lines", but it seems like you misunderstood what the integer parameters to those functions do.

Those number do *not* specify the number of the line to read, but the maximum bytes [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) will read.

```
>>> f = open("data.txt")
>>> f.readline(1)
'5'
>>>f.readline(100)
'48098\n'
```

Both commands will read from the first line, which is `548098`; the first will only read `1` byte, and the second command reads the rest of the line, as there are less than 100 bytes left. If you call `readline` again, it will continue with the second line, etc.

Similarly, [`f.readlines(10)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) will read full lines until the *total* amount of bytes read is larger than the specified number:

```
>>> f.readlines(10)
['968516\n', '853181\n']
```